# Dictionary return output gives pairs of key: value in seperate lines instead one long line

Tags: python

I need to define a function that finds substrings in a string `s`, each substring being in length `k`, the function returns a dictionary whose keys are the substrings, and values are lists of all the indexes of the substring in `s`.

Here is what I have so far, but for some reason, the output of the dictionary is each pair of key: values in separate lines rather than a list of all the pairs:

```
def find_substring_locations(s, k):
    substring_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(s) - k + 1):
        substring = s[i:i+k]
        if substring not in substring_dict:
            all_sub_indexes = []
            sub_index = s.find(substring)
            while sub_index != -1:
                all_sub_indexes.append(sub_index)
                sub_index = s.find(substring, sub_index + 1)
            substring_dict[substring] = all_sub_indexes
    return substring_dict

find_substring_locations('TTAATTAGGGGCGC', 2)
```

I need the output to be:

```
{'TT': [0, 4], 'TA': [1, 5], 'AA': [2], 'AT': [3], 'AG': [6], 'GG': [7, 8, 9], 'GC': [10, 12], 'CG': [11]}
```

But for some reason, it returns:

```
{'TT': [0, 4],
 'TA': [1, 5],
 'AA': [2],
 'AT': [3],
 'AG': [6],
 'GG': [7, 8, 9],
 'GC': [10, 12],
 'CG': [11]}
```

I tried using a sort function but that didn't help (note that the return needs to be a dictionary and not a string and also I only need to return and not to print).

Comment: Use `print(find_substring_locations('TTAATTAGGGGCGC', 2))` as your last statement

Comment: If you don't need to print, why are you concerned about *how* it prints?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IPython? If so, that would explain it because it pretty-prints dictionaries and other formats by default. Your return type is a dictionary, so your code is doing things correctly:

```py
find_substring_locations('TTAATTAGGGGCGC', 2) == {'TT': [0, 4], 'TA': [1, 5], 'AA': [2], 'AT': [3], 'AG': [6], 'GG': [7, 8, 9], 'GC': [10, 12], 'CG': [11]}
```

That returns `True` for me.

If you `print()` the output, it comes out in one line, too.

TL;DR: you're doing things right but I think you're getting confused by your REPL environment.

Comment: Thanks for answering - I use pycharm and the same thing returns False for me :(